# BigQuery shuffle operations memory exceeded error but no ORDER BY clause in SQL - How to optimize further?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I encounter the below error while running an Airflow job with the below query.

Some research on StackOverflow guided me to posts with similar errors, however, most of the suggestions in those posts are about removing ORDER BY clauses, or OVER clause.

My query does not have such thing, so I'm not sure how it can be optimized further.

**Error**:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Resources exceeded during query execution: 
Your project or organization exceeded the maximum disk and memory limit available 
for shuffle operations. Consider provisioning more slots, reducing query concurrency, 
or using more efficient logic in this job.
```

**SQL**:

```
with table_1 as (
    select * 
    from `project.dataset.source_1`
    where date_param = date_var
)
, 
table_2 as (
    select * 
    from `project.dataset.source_2`
    where date_param = date_var
)

SELECT
    date_var AS date_param,
    table_3.field_1
    , table_3.field_2
    , table_1.field_3
    , table_1.field_4
    , table_1.field_5
    , table_1.field_6
    , table_1.field_7
    , table_1.field_8
    , CASE
        WHEN table_2.field_4 IS NOT NULL THEN table_2.itm_field_8
        ELSE 0
    END AS itm_field_8
    , table_1.field_9
FROM
    table_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2
    ON
        table_1.field_4 = table_2.field_4
    AND
        table_1.field_3 = table_2.field_3
    AND
        table_1.field_5 = table_2.field_5
    AND
        table_1.field_6 = table_2.field_6
    AND
        table_1.field_7 = table_2.field_7
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT distinct  
        field_4  
        , field_1 
        , field_2 
    FROM `project.dataset.source_3`
    
    WHERE date_param = date_var
    
    ) AS table_3 
ON table_3.field_4 = table_1.field_4
```

Comment: Have you considered optimizing query performance based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview)?

Comment: Can you consider giving stats. 
1) Also I noticed that you are doing a SELECT * in each of table_1 and table_2, however you are not using table_1.field_1 and table_2.field_1 and table_2.field_2
2) Also am anticipating duplicates in the joins, so consider giving group by in each of the CTE

Comment: @Hemant thanks for replying, stat is as below:  


table_1: 1.02 GB, 11 Bil lines.  


table_2: 1.06 GB, 1 Mil lines.  

For point 1: good point. I actually fixed that already, but it didn't resolve the error


For point 2: this is the business logic of the table so cannot change it.